# Altium - Change Color of Error Text in HUD

Tags: altium, error, drc

I had this set up on my PC a few weeks ago but lost it when I had to switch computers. I am trying to remember how to change the color of the Online DRC Errors shown in the HUD when hovering over the segments causing the error. I do not want to change the color of any of the other text. For example:

[image: HUD]

I want to change the text color of the "Clearance Constraint" entries (or any other DRC errors) to red so that it's easier to pick them out as errors. I know there's a way to color-code the HUD but I can't seem to remember how. I'm using Altium Designer 15.1.

Comment: I don't have Altium 15.1 but for me it's under Preferences -> PCB Editor -> Board Insight Modes

Comment: @I.Wolfe, I'm using Altium 15.1 and you are correct. It is under Preferences -> PCB Editor -> Board Insight Modes. Look for Violation Details.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was on that pane a dozen times but somehow kept overlooking it! @I.Wolfe if you'd like to post that as an answer I will be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it is under Preferences. You go to the PCB Editor folder and click on Board Insight Modes. There you can set the color/font/etc of the different text that pop up with the HUB. Mattias is correct in that it is violation details that you want to change. Here's a picture.

[image]

Glad I could help.